# infimum of a set proof

Tags: calculus

prove that $9/5= \inf\{x\in \mathbb R: x={2n^2+1\over n^2+1}\forall n\text{ even}\}$ I started like this:

let $\epsilon \gt 0$ prove that $\exists N\in \mathbb N$ so that ${2N^2+1\over N^2+1}\lt {9\over 5}+ \epsilon$

$${2N^2+1\over N^2+1}\lt {9\over 5}+ \epsilon \Rightarrow 2-{1\over N^2+1}\lt {9\over 5}+\epsilon$$

$$\Rightarrow {1\over 5}-{1\over N^2+1}\lt \epsilon \Rightarrow {1\over 5}-{1\over N^2+1}\lt 1-{1\over N^2+1}\lt \epsilon$$

but I don´t know what do do next, I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Since the function is increasing in $n$ it is minimized for $n=2$ (unless $n=0$ is considered even).

Comment: you can verify this by noting that the derivative with respect to $n$ is positive.

Comment: thanks but I don´t have to use derivatives

Comment: right, you don't.

Comment: well, my teacher told us that we can´t use them

Comment: Ah.  Well, then just show that $(2(n+1)^2+1)/((n+1)^2+1)$ is always bigger than $(2n^2+1)/(n^2+1)$.  Just take the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you set $$g(n)=\frac{2 n^2+1}{n^2+1}$$
then
$$g\left(2\,n+2\right)-g\left(2\,n\right)={{4\,\left(2\,n+1\right)
 }\over{\left(4\,n^2+1\right)\,\left(4\,n^2+8\,n+5\right)}}\ge 0 ~~~\forall n \ge 0$$

Hence the function is monotonically increasing and if $0$ is included then $\inf = 1$ or else
$$
\inf g(2n) = g(2) = \frac{9}{5}$$